# Is bruteforcing the last character of a salt a good idea?

Tags: mysql, hash, salt

Would it be a good idea security-wise to store salts with their last character removed, and then bruteforce the last character to further the amount of time it would take to create rainbow tables and such? This is assuming the hashing algorithm in use is Whirlpool.

This would make logins take a little longer, but it would be a restriction on bruteforcing speed that cannot be bypassed like other methods can.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Consider switching to [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) which is [deliberately designed to be slow now and continue to be slow in the future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching).

Answer (score 1):

No. Salts are meant to change the string completely - If you think the salt is easily exploit-able, You should make longer salts or change the hash. In addition, It'll take you a lot of uneccessary brute-forcing each time you use the salts.

**Edit**: Just to clearify, I do not think this is a bad method, but the logic is wrong here. Think of it this way - if you can bruteforce the salt, the potencial hacker can do the same. You start a race - at each point you remove more characters from the salt and try to guess who will bruteforce the salt better; and the race ends with you having no salt at all.

Comment: Also, the amount of time to find a single character would be negligible

Answer (score 0):

To clearify one thing: If a user tries to *bruteforce* some login data the salt-complexity itself does not really matter. Each little change affects the hash in a big enough way so he would need a fresh set of rainbow tables.

Since the attacking user does not know anything about he wouldn't mind if you remove 1,2,3 - or even all characters from your salt.

Obfuscating the salt itself is pointless. IF the attacking user somehow gets access to the salt - your database seems to be already compromised. So, in that case he wouldn't care about a correct salt anyway.

Comment: I disagree. First of all, salt might be able to protect you from inside attacks - the attacker might know your various policies, and you still need to be somewhat protected. Besides, if the attack is from the outside and somehow they know the hashing algorithm, bruteforcing the salt is actually an option - however, usually it shouldn't be, because you use secure, long, random salts along with trusty hashs.

Answer (score 0):

No this would not be a good idea, it misses the purpose of the salt. A unique salt per password prevents an attacker from getting all passwords at once with one single rainbow-table. It does it even if the salt is known, and it's better not to mix it up with other "improvements".

The time you would need for the mini-brute-force game, you should better spend in a higher cost factor. That said, you should switch to an algorithm wich offers a cost factor and needs a certain amount of time to calculate the hash (BCrypt, PBKDF2 or SCrypt).

Actually you try to add a server side secret to the hash (an attacker has to find out that one character is missing and must be brute-forced). Adding such a secret can be done in a much more effective way. Just encrypt (two-way) the already calculated hash with a strong server side key, this way the attacker needs to learn about the key before he can start brute-forcing. You can find a more indepth explanation at the end of my [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) about safely storing passwords.